# How to handle multiple merge requests per issue in Gitlab?

Tags: git, gitlab

1. Create an issue in Gitlab
2. From this issue UI: create a Merge Request (a new branch will be created automatically)
3. Commit changes to the branch
4. From the MR UI in Gitlab: merge the MR with squash and delete the branch

Now, let's say, issue was not resolved and we have to move it back to development and create new MR, which in turn will create a branch with the same name. In this case we have a problem:

Developer, who was committing changes to the first MR, has wrong commits history on his local machine, because of commits `squash` during merge. To resolve it, he'll have to hard reset `origin/branch_name` <= this doesn't look like a widely used conventional procedure. What is the right way to handle or prevent this situation?

Comment: You could create a branch manually with a new name and connect further commits to the issue with the '#[issuenumber] commit message' and from that new branch you could create a new merge request.

Comment: the point of UI is to make this easier. Creating branch locally etc is quite a few extra steps. This doesn't look better than hard resetting.

Comment: I didn't mean to create the branch locally but in GitLab with the UI (= remote branch). If you do it with this way, if I counted correctly, you only have 1 extra-click.